# Ffmpeg one image video convert faster

Tags: performance, ffmpeg

At the moment I can convert a video with one image and an mp3. I was wondering how I can make the converting faster, because it takes 5min to render one image and place an mp3 of 3min.

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i track.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest final.mp4
```

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three easy things you can do:

- Choose a faster `-preset` as mentioned by Ronald.
- Use a lower frame rate, such as `-framerate 2` (I've seen a few players choke on 1 fps, but that was ages ago). This needs to be an input option, so place it before `-i`.
- [Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it. If the player doesn't like MP3 audio in MP4 container then use a better player such as VLC or mpv, or use a different output container such as Matroska (mkv). If those suggestions don't work for you then you'll simply just have to re-encode.

Comment: Thanks mate!! The preset and framerate workef perfect! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) page, section 2 ("Choose a preset"), specifically this section:

> The general guideline is to use the slowest preset that you have
>   patience for. Current presets in descending order of speed are:
>   ultrafast,superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower,
>   veryslow, placebo. The default preset is medium.

So, try -preset:v ultrafast. Note that you didn't tell us what resolution your image is, so I can't tell if 5 minutes for a 3-minute encode is sensible or not (regardless of the fact that it's a still image).